# Can I relay the data received from Netcat to a URL as a POST?

Tags: curl, netcat

I have a PHP-based website, and I'm trying to integrate it with another system.

This system sends XML data to a specific port (let's say port 9999). I am able to capture the incoming data and save it to a text file using netcat. However, my goal is to process this XML data using PHP and then send a response back to the other system.

Essentially, I want to receive data on port 9999 and then send it as POST data to a specific URL, possibly using cURL.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04.

Is it possible to achieve this or am I approaching it the wrong way?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: `possibly using cURL` do you know how to `POST` using `cURL`?

Comment: I do, but I'm not sure how to get the payload from netcat across to cURL.

Comment: can't you just save the data you get from netcat into a file, then use the file for post body? Or is netcat a long running process, i.e. it doesn't stop after you receive the data once?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I believe I have found a solution. I just did a crash course on bash scripts and am doing it like this:

`nc -l -p 9999 | ./relay.sh`

And the relay.sh file looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  output+=$line
done

curl -X POST https://relayurl.com/phpfile.php -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "${output}"

nc -l -p 9999 | ./relay.sh
```

It seems to be working well, but I welcome any suggestions or improvements.

Comment: First, I'm glad that you did it by yourself. Many people come here asking questions with no prior knowledge waiting for someone to do the job for them, so I'm happy you started to learn `bash` scripting.

Comment: In the man pages of `curl`, in the part about the `-d` flag, you could see: _"If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin."_ So instead of reading all the lines in a loop, a simple solution would be to redirect `nc` to a file: `nc -l -p 9999 > /tmp/data.xml`, and then just use the file with `-d @/tmp/data.xml` in `curl`.

Comment: And since `curl` can even read the data from stdin, a trivial one line solution would be: `nc -l -p 9999 | curl -X POST https://relayurl.com/phpfile.php -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @-`. The output of your `nc` will go directly to `curl`'s stdin through the pipe, which would use it as a data because of the `-d @-` flag.

Comment: That's a very tidy approach @aviro, thank you for your help. So here comes the latest challenge, I need to be able to send the resulting output from the cURL request back to the client that initiated the connection, as part of __the same__ connection. Is that even possible? So it's like this: my server is listening on port 9999, a connection gets made by the client, I grab the payload, process it via PHP and send back the result as part of the same connection. It's just that final stage I'm struggling with, everything else is working beautifully.